# 3d image rotation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript and I want to write a function which makes 3D rotation.
For 2D rotation (over Z axis) I have the following code, but I want to make 3D rotation of context.

The code:

```
<img id="glass_1_orig" src="glass_1_orig.png" alt="Glass N1" width="94" height="45"/>
<canvas id="overlay" width="400" height="300"></canvas>

var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var overlayCC = overlay.getContext('2d');

function drawRotatedImage(x1, y1, xAngle, yAngle, zAngle, length) { 
    var glassImage = document.getElementById('glass_1_orig');
    var ratio = length/glassImage.width;

    overlayCC.save();
    overlayCC.translate(x1, y1);

    overlayCC.rotate(zAngle);
    overlayCC.drawImage(glassImage,0,0,glassImage.width,glassImage.height,-(ratio*27),-(ratio*19),length,ratio*glassImage.height);

    overlayCC.restore(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle demo if possible?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s94y3/